# Added values to an Object is changed whenever I add a new one

Tags: lightning-aura-components, modal

I am trying to save a new values into an Object from a modal, but not pushing it yet to the database. I successfully pushed the new values to the Object, but once I wanted to push another value into the Object, the previous inserted value was changed as well.

Upon creating the 1st value
[image]

When I add another one or the 2nd value
[image]

Notice that the Test 1 values was changed to the values of the recently added ones

Here's what I have so far:

```
saveModal : function(component, event, helper){
    var newAccountForm = component.get("v.accountForm");
    var accountList = component.get("v.accountList");
    var newAccList = [...accountList,newAccountForm];
    component.set("v.accountList",newAccList);
    helper.closeModal(component,event,helper);
},
```

I tried to do this `accountList.push(newAccountForm)` but I get the same results, the previous inserted value was changed as well, it mirrors the latest value added.

On my 2nd creation/save, the new inserted accountList value was change prior to setting its new value.

Answer (score 1):

In Object-Oriented Programming, we have the concept of "references." Multiple variables can refer to the same physical object in memory.

For example, observe the following:

```
let x = { value: 10 }
let y = x;
y.value = 20;
console.log(x.value); // 20
```

Because both variables point to the same object, you only have one object, so a change in one variable will appear to change the other as well.

To fix this, copy the object:

```
var newAccList = [...accountList,{...newAccountForm}];
```

Where `{...someObject}` will make a new object with a copy of the top-level elements (it is a "shallow" copy).

To illustrate with our example, above:

```
let x = { value: 10 }
let y = {...x};
y.value = 20;
console.log(x.value); // 10
console.log(y.value); // 20
```

If you happen to need a recursive, or "deep", copy, you'll want to do some research on such as method. In many cases, it can be written as:

```
var newAccList = [...accountList,JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newAccountForm))];
```

Where we make a round-trip through a JSON string. This won't work for self-referential structures, though:

```
var value = { word: 'bird' }
value.otherWord = value;
```

See more information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/122102/2132791) on Stack Overflow.